# Is there an option to find exact match of data and && condition in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I have a sign-in form. And I have stored our user information in MongoDB Atlas https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/.

**My data is like**

```
    _id:60a64bee48f6eed16a566cf5
    user_name:"test1"
    user_password:"123456"

    _id:60a64bee48f6eed16a566cf5
    user_name:"test2"
    user_password:"abcdef"

   _id:60a64bee48f6eed16a566cf5
    user_name:"test3"
    user_password:"123456"
```

And I should retrieve the data that both user_name and user_password match.

**My code is**

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
 let userName = req.body.user_name;
 let userPassword = req.body.user_password;
 userCollection.find({user_name: userName}).toArray()
 .then(results => {
    console.log('success');
    res.redirect('/')
    // console.log(results)
 })
 .catch(err => {
    console.error(error)
 })
})
```

And my question is any other option to find the document that match the data *like given user_name and user_password should match*

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query

```
userCollection.find( { $and: [ {user_name: userName, user_password: userPassword } ] } )
```

we should never store the password directly in your DB,  you should first encrypt the password by using any encryption library then store it in DB

Answer (score 1):

- Try this code its seems easy to understand verify both password and username

  ```
   userCollection.find({user_name: userName},function(err,foundUser){

               if(!err){
                  if(foundUser.userPassword == userPassword){
                   console.log('success');
                    res.redirect('/');

                  }

             }
              else{
            console.log(err);
  ```

}

});

```
 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
userCollection.find({user_name: userName, user_password: userPassword })
```

You can use `findOne` instead of `find`

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/findOne/

```
userCollection.findOne({user_name: userName, user_password: userPassword })
```

---

Note:- Don't store raw passwords, store hashed password

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt to hash passwords.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you give the example code for implementing findOne. I don't know how to apply this.